# How Do I convert bytes to ASCII chars, using Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a problem with conversion this bytes to ASCII chars, need to do similar conversion using Oracle PL/SQL, the original one is in MS SQLserver:

```
   /// </summary> 

/// <param name="blob"></param>

/// <returns></returns> 

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true)] 

public static String VarbinaryToVarchar(SqlBytes blob) 
{ 
    if (blob.IsNull) return null; 

    byte[] buffer = blob.Buffer; 
    char[] res = new char[buffer.Length * 2]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++) 
    { 
        res[i * 2] = (char)((buffer[i] & 0xF) + 65); 
        res[i * 2 + 1] = (char)(((buffer[i] >> 4) & 0xF) + 65); 
    } 
    return new String(res); 
}
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Do you only want help from people who know SQL Server, or also from people who only work with Oracle? I have no clue what your code is supposed to do; can you explain your requirement in common language? Never mind how it is solved in code.

Comment: Is your requirement how to change from binary to ascii in oracle?

Comment: The problem is that I dont really know how that algorithm works...I just got that one and need to do similar in Oracle...Only what I know is for input: 
0000EB862CB8024892CD419A26BB3AE
It's gonna give me output: 
AAAALOGIMCILCAIEJNBEKJGCLIDLOK
Just need to figure out how it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could explore the use of Oracle built-in `UTL_RAW` coupled with `HEXTORAW`, then convert your hex. value to integer and add "65". After that, `CHR` will give you the `ASCII` you expect:

```
 declare
   p_s_in varchar2(1000):= '0000EB862CB8024892CD419A26BB3AE';
   l_s_cmp varchar2(1000):= 'AAAALOGIMCILCAIEJNBEKJGCLIDLOK';
   l_s_out varchar2(1000) :='';
   p_pad binary_integer:=1;
   l_cur1 char;
   l_cur2 char;
   l_cur_bi1 binary_integer;
   l_cur_bi2 binary_integer;
 begin

   l_cur1 := substr(p_s_in, 1,1);
   l_cur2 := substr(p_s_in, 2, 1);
   while (length(l_cur1)=1)
   loop
     l_cur_bi1 := UTL_RAW.cast_to_binary_integer(HEXTORAW(l_cur1))+65;
     l_cur_bi2 := UTL_RAW.cast_to_binary_integer(HEXTORAW(l_cur2))+65;

     dbms_output.put_line(l_cur2||'->'||chr(l_cur_bi2)||'?>'||substr(l_s_cmp, 1,1));
     l_s_cmp := substr(l_s_cmp, 2);

     dbms_output.put_line(l_cur1||'->'||chr(l_cur_bi1)||'?>'||substr(l_s_cmp, 1,1));
     l_s_out:=l_s_out||chr(l_cur_bi2)||chr(l_cur_bi1);
     -- end loop
     p_s_in := substr(p_s_in, 3);
     l_s_cmp := substr(l_s_cmp, 2);
     l_cur1 := substr(p_s_in, 1, 1);
     l_cur2 := substr(p_s_in, 2, 1);
   end loop;
   dbms_output.put_line(l_s_out);
 end;
 /
```

I let debugging output, because I'm not completely sure this is what you're looking for. You gave us an output that slightly differs from what I get with your code:
[image]
... you or I might be missing something.